# pytorch - passing image original size to transform function

Tags: python, pytorch, albumentations

I am using pytorch with albumentations for image transformations in a sementic segmentation model.

For some transformations, I need to pass the original image size as parameters but I just dont know how I can do it.

I have the transforms function and my dataset class in seperate modules like below. In the `medium_transform()` function in `transforms.py`, I would like to have access to the `original_height` and `original_width` that I am passing through `self.transforms(**result)` in `dataset.py`.

**dataset.py**

```
from torch.utils.data import Dataset
import cv2

class SegmentationDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, imagePaths, maskPaths, transforms):
        self.imagePaths = imagePaths
        self.maskPaths = maskPaths
        self.transforms = transforms

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        image = cv2.imread(self.imagePaths[idx], cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        mask = cv2.imread(self.maskPaths[idx], 0)
        result = {"image": image, "mask": mask, "original_height": image.shape[0], "original_width": image.shape[1]}

        # check to see if we are applying any transformations
        if self.transforms is not None:
            result = self.transforms(**result)

        return result
```

**transforms.py**

```
import albumentations as A
from . import config

def medium_transforms(**params):
    print(params) #here params is an empty dict
    return [
        A.OneOf([
          A.RandomSizedCrop(min_max_height=(50, 101), height=params["original_height"], width=params["original_width"], p=config.MEDIUM_TRANSFORMS_PROBABILITY),
          A.PadIfNeeded(min_height=params["original_height"], min_width=params["original_width"], p=config.MEDIUM_TRANSFORMS_PROBABILITY)
      ], p=1)
    ]

def compose(transforms_to_compose):
    # combine all augmentations into single pipeline
    return A.Compose([
      item for sublist in transforms_to_compose for item in sublist
    ])
```

**train.py**

```
import torch
from . import transforms
from .dataset import SegmentationDataset

trainImages = ["./images/test.png"]
trainMasks = ["./masks/test.png"]

train_transforms = transforms.compose([
  transforms.medium_transforms()
])

train_dataset = SegmentationDataset(imagePaths=trainImages, maskPaths=trainMasks, transforms=train_transforms)
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to use partial functions.

**transforms.py:**

```
import albumentations as A
from functools import partial
from . import config

def medium_transforms(original_height, original_width, **params):
    return [
        A.OneOf([
            A.RandomSizedCrop(min_max_height=(50, 101), height=original_height, width=original_width, p=config.MEDIUM_TRANSFORMS_PROBABILITY),
            A.PadIfNeeded(min_height=original_height, min_width=original_width, p=config.MEDIUM_TRANSFORMS_PROBABILITY)
        ], p=1)
    ]

def compose(transforms_to_compose):
    return A.Compose([item for sublist in transforms_to_compose for item in sublist])

medium_transforms_partial = partial(medium_transforms, original_height=None, original_width=None)
```

**train.py:**

```
import torch
from . import transforms
from .dataset import SegmentationDataset

trainImages = ["./images/test.png"]
trainMasks = ["./masks/test.png"]

train_transforms = transforms.compose([
  transforms.medium_transforms_partial
])

train_dataset = SegmentationDataset(imagePaths=trainImages, maskPaths=trainMasks, transforms=train_transforms)
```

In this code, the `functools.partial` function creates a partially applied function `medium_transforms_partial` with original_height and original_width as parameters. This allows you to pass these parameters when you call `medium_transforms_partial`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have tried your suggestion but in the `medium_transforms` function `original_height` and `original_width` are `None`. The values from the `**result` are not passed even with using `partial`